# JavaFX setTabcontent dynamically

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, javafx-8

I have made an application which uses tabpane. I am able to set tooltip and title of each tab dynamically. But how do I set its contents dynamically. I am sure that I can maintain a list of Node object and add it to tab during iteration, but I feel there are other ways to do it. Here is what I have done so far.

```
public class Index extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    final String[] tabContent={"title1"
            ,"title2"
            ,"title3"
            ,"title4"
            ,"title5"};
    final String[] tabToolTip={"tooltip1"
            ,"tooltip2"
            ,"tooltip3"
            ,"tooltip4"
            ,"tooltip5"};


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         primaryStage.setTitle("Ipas Utility");
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600, Color.ALICEBLUE);
            TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
            tabPane.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Hover on each tab for an overview"));
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              Tab tab = new Tab();
              tab.setText(tabContent[i]);
              tab.setClosable(false);
              tab.setTooltip(new Tooltip(tabToolTip[i]));
              HBox hbox = new HBox();
              hbox.getChildren().add(new Label(tabContent[i]));
              hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
              tab.setContent(hbox);;
              tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            }
            // bind to take available space
            borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
            borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

            borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
            root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

How I can maintain tabcontent in a list/array outside `start` block?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite okay what you did. Here's a modified version of your code which allows you to add a tab on button click:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static int tabCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab());
        tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab());
        tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab());

        Button addTabButton = new Button( "Add Tab");
        addTabButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab());
        });

        Button logButton = new Button( "Log");
        logButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            for( Tab tab: tabPane.getTabs()) {
                System.out.println( "Tab " + tab.getText() + " has content " + tab.getContent());
            }
        });

        HBox toolbar = new HBox();
        HBox.setMargin(addTabButton, new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        HBox.setMargin(logButton, new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        toolbar.getChildren().addAll( addTabButton, logButton);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(toolbar);
        root.setCenter(tabPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static Tab createTab() {

        tabCount++;

        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + tabCount);
        tab.setTooltip( new Tooltip( "Tooltip Tab " + tabCount));

        Node content = new Label( "Content Tab " + tabCount);
        tab.setContent(content);

        return tab;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In order to access the tabs you can use [getTabs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#getTabs--). And in order to change the content, i. e. the node that represents the content, you can use [setContent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setContent-javafx.scene.Node-).

The example code shows you how to iterate through the tabs by pressing the log button.